# How to let user select images to attach using email intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

So, i was working on this idea where i can let user select an image from a folder when they click on a button and that particular image/images can be send as an attachment using email intent in android. I have been successful in sending one picture or many pictures but the fact is i have to declare those images in my code. I want something like OpenFileDialog which can allow me to choose an image at runtime. Is there a way to do that?

```
 case R.id.button2:
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.reccomendation_subject));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.recomendation_body));
                    emailIntent.setType("image/png");

                    File bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test_1.png");
                    Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);


                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));



                    break;
```

Comment: You need to create a file explorer for that. There is no inbuilt file explorer provided by SDK to select files.

Comment: You could make the user select the image before on a listView on your app. And the list would show files from your sdcard. Just an idea